# how to remove key+value from hash in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given

```
var myHash = new Array();
myHash['key1'] = { Name: 'Object 1' };
myHash['key2'] = { Name: 'Object 2' };
myHash['key3'] = { Name: 'Object 3' };
```

How do I remove `key2`, and `object 2` from the hash, so that it ends up in a state as if I did:

```
var myHash = new Array();
myHash['key1'] = { Name: 'Object 1' };
myHash['key3'] = { Name: 'Object 3' };
```

delete doesn't do what I want;

```
delete myHash['key2']
```

simply gives me this:

```
var myHash = new Array();
myHash['key1'] = { Name: 'Object 1' };
myhash['key2'] = null;
myHash['key3'] = { Name: 'Object 3' };
```

the only docs I can find on `splice` and `slice` deal with integer indexers, which I don't have.

Edit: I also do not know that 'key2' is necessarily in position [1]

**UPDATE**

OK slight red herring, delete does seem to do what I want on the surface, however, I'm using json2.js to stringify my object to json for pushing back to the server,

after I've deleted, myHash gets serialized as:

```
[ { Name: 'Object 1' }, null, { Name: 'Object 3' } ]
```

Is this a bug in json2.js? or is it something I'm doing wrong with delete?

Thanks

Comment: What you're doing is adding properties to an object, which is different than adding elements to an array/hash.  You're looking for a way to remove a property, more or less.  Try delete myHash.key1, as mentioned in other comments.

Comment: If it's a hashtable, you should use `var myHash = new Object()` instead of `var myHash = new Array()`.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You're looking for [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator):

```
delete myhash['key2']
```

See the [Core Javascript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide)

Comment: I thought this was correct, thats why i tried it in the first place. It does _seem_ to work, my problem actually lies in Json.stringify, ill update the question

Comment: use the splice function instead.  Delete leaves a hole in the array.

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is the aforementioned splice function btw.

Comment: This is not the best option when the changes to `myhash` should take place in the current scope only. `delete` may have side effects if variables elsewhere refer to the `myhash` object.

Answer (score 11):

Why do you use `new Array();` for hash? You need to use `new Object()` instead.

And i think you will get what you want.

Comment: I don't like new at all. I prefer var myHash = [];

Comment: Or in this case, myHash={}; :-)

Comment: I agree.
The only thing that an array gives you is a length which doesn't ever work when you change the indexer something other than an int.

Answer (score 6):

You say you don't necessarily know that 'key2' is in position [1]. Well, it's not. Position 1 would be occupied by myHash[1].

You're abusing JavaScript arrays, which (like functions) allow key/value hashes. Even though JavaScript allows it, it does not give you facilities to deal with it, as a language designed for associative arrays would. JavaScript's array methods work with the numbered properties only.

The first thing you should do is switch to objects rather than arrays. You don't have a good reason to use an array here rather than an object, so don't do it. If you want to use an array, just number the elements and give up on the idea of hashes. The intent of an array is to hold information which can be indexed into numerically.

You can, of course, put a hash (object) into an array if you like.

```
myhash[1]={"key1","brightOrangeMonkey"};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option may be this [John Resig remove method](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/). can better fit what you need. if you know the index in the array.

Comment: well not having the index is exactly what the question states

Comment: Hey @AndrewBullock I have one query I get JSON array Ex: [{\"Countrycode\":\"DE\",\"count\":\"3\"}] but i want to get like[{"DE":"3"}] like this but i don't get this output Please help me